# Unable to display inline images in Spacemacs

Tags: image, emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

I have the following image link defined in an org file.
`[[file:~/image.jpeg]]`

Whilst clicking on the link opens the image in a new buffer, I can't get the file to display inline images.

I've tried:

Adding `#+STARTUP: inlineimages` to the org file itself.

Adding `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)` to the user-config in .spacemacs.

Adding the following to the user-config in .spacemacs.

```
(defun do-org-show-all-inline-images ()
  (interactive)
  (org-display-inline-images t t))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C v")
                'do-org-show-all-inline-images)
```

None of these enable inline images by default, or via

`C-x C-c C-v`

which produces:

`No images to display here`

**Emacs**: 27.2
**Spacemacs** (base):  0.999.0
**Image**: 474 x 355 pixels, 27kb

Comment: What is the return value of `(image-file-name-regexp)`? Does it match a `.jpeg` extension?

Comment: I can't find that function  with execute command (```SPC SPC```) does it go by any other name?

Comment: No. It's not a command (i.e. not `interactive`). Add the expresion to the `*scratch*` buffer and press `C-j` after the closing paren. Or create a `lisp-mode` buffer, enter the expression and press `C-x C-e` after the closing paren, Or try `M-:` and enter the expression in the `Eval: ` prompt. All these can be done in regular Emacs, so I hope one or more can be done in Doom.

Comment: thanks, I got it working by creating an elisp source block in the org file.  Here's the output ```: \.\(GIF\|JP\(?:E?G\)\|P\(?:BM\|GM\|N[GM]\|PM\)\|SVG\|TIFF?\|X\(?:[BP]M\)\|gif\|jp\(?:e?g\)\|p\(?:bm\|gm\|n[gm]\|pm\)\|svg\|tiff?\|x\(?:[bp]m\)\)\'
```

Comment: OK - that should work. All I can suggest is to edebug `org-toggle-inline-images` and `org-display-inline-images` and step through them to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Switched from spacemacs-base to the vanilla distribution.
Now adding:

```
#+STARTUP: inlineimages
```

to the header of the org file enables inline images to be displayed by default.